# Conflict on two post on single page form (HTML) and PHP

Tags: php

I need to keep two forms for login and logout in one single page including PHP and HTML like

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"> 
<input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"  value="Get in"/>
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="logoutButton"  value="Logout"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

on PHP part I have

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ 
  $inputuser = $_POST['username']; 
  $_SESSION['user'] = 'A';
 } 

if(isset($_POST['logoutButton'])){ 
      unset($_SESSION['user']);
      header('Location: http://somewhere.com/');  
}
```

As I said I have to keep everything on one single page but this looks like causing conflict between the POST(s). How can I stop this and target each POST properly?

Comment: Why do you need logout as a form when you're not even posting anything?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "causing conflict between the POSTs"? What specifically do you have a question about?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson,  I am using this form in WordPress `header.php`

Comment: `session_start();`?

Comment: what is the error now?

Comment: If you're using WP and have this in your "header.php", I bet that you will find some "Headers already sent"-messages in your error log.